# Emacs WebMode code completion for html and css

Tags: html, css, emacs, code-completion

I have setup the plugin for webmode in emacs but I am unable to get the code completion working for html and css. I am using the company mode plugin. Any links or assistance welcome.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to the latest web-mode, then use ctags/etags to create TAGS.

This is your project setup in ~/.emacs:
`(setq tags-table-list (list "~/proj/js/TAGS" "~/projs/css/TAGS")`

See https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/pull/640 for tech details.